# Plug headphone not support with macmini

Tags: audio, mac-mini, headphones, repair

I have a Macmini 4,1. I tried to use plug headset with mic for skype call, but it doesn't work.

I can hear the voice from the other end, but my voice can't be heard on the other end. I tried with two or three headsets, but results the same.

Then, a friend asked me to try using USB headset, I brought it from one neighbour and now it works fine.why?

Is it a problem of my macmini, or all macmini would behave like this?

Referring to the answer, I have to decide to buy a new USB headset or not.

Comment: What plug does the headset have?

Comment: 3.5 mm plug(two plugs red and green for mike and speeker) we can see the holes in the macmini that fits it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here are the specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini#Specifications_3) for this mini according to Wikipedia. Note that this Mac (and most Macs I'm familiar with) has an audio line-in which is a high-level input, but no mic-in (low level). That means you'll need an external microphone amplifier between the mic and the line-in input. The USB mic is doing all of that for you - amplifying the mic and converting the audio signal to digital.

Answer (score 1):

When you plug the cable in for the microphone, you may also need to enable this input in System Preferences. Go to *System Preferences > Sound > Input* and make sure your headset is listed and selected here.

I've found that USB audio devices typically auto-select themselves when plugged in, but devices plugged into the audio jacks don't normally auto-select.

If this doesn't work for you, you may need to get the Mac mini looked at by a tech, as it could be indicative of an actual hardware problem.

Comment: From the OP's comment, I suspect he's got a headset with separate jacks for the headphones and the mic, and is trying to plug the mic jack into the mini's audio line-in, which probably won't work, or will at least require him to use line-in and not microphone as his audio source...

Answer (score 0):

New Mac Minis have "Mic In" ports, but you have to use the 4-conductor phone-type plug - the mic in is one of the contacts on the headphone-out plug.

So in this case you'd need an adapter (like what you'd use to use the headset with an iPhone).